# How to have separated but vinculated multiple Ubuntu One accounts?

Tags: ubuntu-one

I would like to use 1 account for keeping private files synchronised and another for business files, which will be read by others. I have different e-mail addresses for business and private.

The private arrangement is between home, office and laptop. The business arrangement is between these plus business partners.

I have tried setting up this arrangement but my efforts are not successful. Is thus possible? If so, how do I instruct the Ubuntu One Manager which folder should be synchronised in which account?

Comment: It might be possible using two different users on ubuntu and signing up for two different ubuntu one accounts.

Answer (score 5):

There isn't any support in the client for managing multiple accounts in the Ubuntu One client software.

That said, you should be able to achieve the above using a single account:

1. Create one account for you, and have your business partners do the same.
2. Put the files you want to share with business partners into a folder synchronised by Ubuntu One (either under `~/Ubuntu One`, or another folder you've asked to synchronise).
3. Right click on this folder, and select `Share...` under the `Ubuntu One` submenu and enter the email addresses of the people you want to share the folder with.  If you want them to be able to modify files in the folder, give them write access at this point.
4. Have your business partners accept the shared folder.  The shared folder should appear under their `~/Ubuntu One` folder.