# Multiple Ubuntu One accounts on one computer

Tags: ubuntu-one

Is this possible? For example, one for me@myself.tld, one for first_name.last_name@my_work.tld.

$ Ubuntu One - first
  my_stuff/

$ Ubuntu One - second
  work/
  shared_with_coworkers/

Comment: In English, please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of
[How do I manage multiple ubuntuone accounts?][1]


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/64517/how-do-i-manage-multiple-ubuntuone-accounts

Comment: The service is obsolete

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to have separated but vinculated multiple Ubuntu One accounts?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/36048/how-to-have-separated-but-vinculated-multiple-ubuntu-one-accounts)